# How to find column names of the table created using SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have created a table using SQL and I forgot to insert the values and I want to know what are the columns so that I can insert the values. How to find column names?

```
CREATE TABLE Employee1 (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  salary INT,
  location VARCHAR(20),
  gender CHAR(1)
  );
```

Comment: The column names are id, name, salary, location, and gender obviously.

Comment: I don't believe this is a real question. The column names are given in the table definition that you've posted.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I have asked this as an interview question and I didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you taged `MYSQL` Database, you can use this command:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE Databasename.tablename;
```

or:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM Databasename.tablename;
```

or:

```
describe Databasename.tablename;
```